# Introduction to Algorithm, Exercise 10.2-4

Tags: algorithm

This is a question from exercise of **Introduction to Algorithms**, 3rd edtion:
(I know this is trivial question, but I can't get my head around this.)

Chapter 10, page 240:

> ***10.2-4***
>
> As written, each loop iteration in the LIST-SEARCH procedure requires
>   two tests: one for `x != L.nil` and one for `x.key != k`. Show how to
>   eliminate the test for `x != L.nil` in each iteration.

```
LIST-SEARCH(L, k)
  x = L.nil.next
  while x != L.nil and x.key != k
    x = x.next
  return x
```

`L` is circular, doubly linked list with a sentinel. (A sentinel is a fixed static element in the starting, that helps to simplify boundary conditions. For example, suppose that we provide with list `L` an object `L.nil` that represents `NIL` but has all the attributes of other objects in the list.)

Unless, `k` you search for is always present, simple removing `x != L.nil` would cause infinite iteration.

You can transform, this expression `x != L.nil` to other expressions (such as count of elements in the list), but that isn't a solution, I guess.

What am I lacking in solving this question?

Comment: Please explain the down votes.

Comment: What if you set `L.NIL`'s key to `k` temporarily? Other than "representing `NIL`", it has all of the other attributes the other list items have, right? Is there some restriction that says you cannot do this?

Comment: @ChronoKitsune I believe that this is just a teaser, there are no significant advantages (performance or readability) of doing this. These sentinels exist conventionally, to identify the end points of the list.

Comment: Undoubtedly there exist microprocessors on which installing a sentinel `k` is faster.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Prepend sentinel. Using the sentinel, `x.key == k` condition will met anyway. Ensure sentinel deletion.

```
LIST-SEARCH(L, k)
    LIST-INSERT(L, k)
    x = L.head.next
    while x.key != k
        x = x.next
    if x == L.head
        ret = NIL
    else
        ret = x
    LIST-DELETE(L, L.head)
    return ret
```

Comment: Can you please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71136657/algorithm-clrs-solution-more-in-depth-discussion-need

Answer (score 14):

The trick is to set your sentinel's key to value `k` before entering the loop. That way, you can eliminate the `nil` check and still be sure the loop terminates. When `k` is found,  the node found is either the sentinel, or the value you wanted to find.

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this:

```
LIST-SEARCH(L,k)
    nil.key = k;
    currentPtr = nil.next;
         while(currentPtr.key != k) 
    currentPtr = currentPtr.next;
    nil.data = -1; // dummy key
    return currentPtr;
```